# Encountering issue with running a spark job in zeppelin notebook

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I've been trying to debug this for the past week with no luck. At first I thought this was a serialization error because of the recusrive calls to `readSerialData`, however even when I try and operate on the DataFrame and just return a vector (first using a `mapPartition` and then just using a `map` even though it's inefficient), I still encounter the same error.

This is the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkZeppelinContext
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:524)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.findClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:26)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:34)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ParentClassLoader.loadClass(ParentClassLoader.scala:30)
    at org.apache.spark.repl.ExecutorClassLoader.findClass(ExecutorClassLoader.scala:82)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:419)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:352)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2068)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getDeclaredSUID(ObjectStreamClass.java:1857)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$700(ObjectStreamClass.java:79)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:506)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$3.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:494)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:391)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:681)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1939)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1805)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2096)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1624)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2341)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2265)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2123)
```

Has anyone encountered this before? Any pointers on how to start debugging this is greatly appreciated.